# "import tensorflow" results in error: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function' (Python in Jupyter Lab)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter, object-detection-api

Python 3.9.12.
Windows 10.
jupyterlab 3.3.2.

```
Import tensorflow
```

When I try to import Tensorflow, I get the following 'tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function' error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [44], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow

File ~\OD13\TFODCourse\tfod13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:45
     42 from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
     43 _tf2.enable()
---> 45 from ._api.v2 import __internal__
     46 from ._api.v2 import __operators__
     47 from ._api.v2 import audio

File ~\OD13\TFODCourse\tfod13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py:14
     12 from . import eager_context
     13 from . import feature_column
---> 14 from . import function
     15 from . import graph_util
     16 from . import mixed_precision

File ~\OD13\TFODCourse\tfod13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\function\__init__.py:8
      3 """Public API for tf.__internal__.function namespace.
      4 """
      6 import sys as _sys
----> 8 from tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function.polymorphic_function import Function
      9 from tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function.quarantine import defun_with_attributes

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function'
```

My workflow is based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U

I found the following answer, but I'm not understanding how to implement the TFLite Authoring Tool to solve this problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177865/tensorflow-python-eager-polymorphic-function-no-module-error-on-imports](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question:
I created a conda environment and installed an older version of Python (3.7) in it and that seems to have fixed the problem.

I found these links to be helpful:
[How to downgrade the Python Version from 3.8 to 3.7 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794105/how-to-downgrade-the-python-version-from-3-8-to-3-7-on-windows)
[conda install downgrade python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630002/conda-install-downgrade-python-version)
[Jupyter Notebook - Cannot Connect to Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955563/jupyter-notebook-cannot-connect-to-kernel)
[How to find the version of jupyter notebook from within the notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323745/how-to-find-the-version-of-jupyter-notebook-from-within-the-notebook)
[pip command to downgrade jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65592982/pip-command-to-downgrade-jupyter-notebook)
[How to check python anaconda version installed on Windows 10 PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342098/how-to-check-python-anaconda-version-installed-on-windows-10-pc)
https://towardsdatascience.com/get-your-conda-environment-to-show-in-jupyter-notebooks-the-easy-way-17010b76e874